# Debugging a minidump in Visual Studio where the call stack is null

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, minidump

I have a customer who is getting a 100% reproduceable crash that I can't replicate in my program compiled in Visual Studio 2005. I sent them a debug build of my program and kept all the PDB and DLL files handy. They sent me the minidump file, but when I open it I get:

"Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in MiniDump.dmp: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

Then the call stack shows only "0x00000000()" and the disassembly shows me a dump of the memory at 0x0. I've set up the symbol server, loaded my PDB symbols, etc. But I can't see any way of knowing which of the many DLLs actually caused the jump to null. This is a large project with many dependencies, and some of them are binaries that I don't have the source or PDBs for, as I am using an API as a 3rd party.

So how on earth is this minidump useful? How do I see which DLL caused the crash? I've never really used minidumps for debugging before, but all the tutorials I have read seem to at least display a function name or something else that gives you a clue in the call stack. I just get the one line pointing to null.

I also tried using "Depends" to see if there was some DLL dependency that was unresolved; however on my three test machines with various Windows OS's, I seem to get three different sets of OS DLL dependencies (and yet can't replicate the crash); so this doesn't seem a particularly reliable method either to diagnose the problem.

What other methods are available to determine the cause of this problem? Is there some way to step back one instruction to see which DLL jumped to null?

Comment: ld ModuleName will load the symbols for a module. !analyze -v will give you a stack trace. Between those two, you should have enough information to get started. http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html has a list of common WinDbg commands.

Comment: You're right Vanessa - I was using the debugger built into Visual Studio, but when I use WinDbg I do get the module name. Is the lesson here: don't use the Visual Studio debugger for stack corrupting post-mortem analysis?

Comment: Anytime I've seen this its been caused by calling a null function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea behind all 'simple' ways of post mortem debugging is the capture of a stack trace. If your application overwrites the stack there is no way for such analysis. Only very sophisticated methods, that record the whole program execution in dedicated hardware could help.

The way to go in such a case are log files. Spread some log statements very wide around the area where the fault occurs and transmit that version to the customer. After the crash you'll see the last log statement in your log file. Add more log statements between that point and the next log statement that has not been recorded in the log file, ship that version again. Repeat until you found the line causing the problem.

I wrote a two part article about this at ddj.com:

[About Log Files Part 1](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/212902973)

[About Log Files Part 2](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/214502427)

Answer (score 5):

Well it looks like the answer in this instance was "Use WinDbg instead of Visual Studio for debugging minidumps". I couldn't get any useful info out of VS, but WinDbg gave me a wealth of info on the chain of function calls that led to the crash.

In this instance it still didn't help solve my problem, as all of the functions were in the 3rd party library I am using, so it looks like the only definitive answer to my specific problem is to use log files to trace the state of my application that leads to the crash.

I guess if anyone else sees a similar problem with an unhelpful call stack when debugging a minidump, the best practice is to open it with WinDgb rather than Visual Studio. Seems odd that the best tool for the job is the free Microsoft product, not the commerical one.

The other lesson here is probably "any program that uses a third party library needs to write a log file".

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation, but the the stack is getting truncated or over-written, might this be a simple case of using an uninitialised field, or perhaps a buffer overrun ?

That might be fairly easy to locate.

Comment: I would expect the runtime debugger to catch it if this was the case. The fact that it only crashes on about 10% of computers makes me think the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set WinDbg on a customer's computer and use it as a default debugger for any application that causes a crash? You just need to add pdb files to the folder where your application resides. When a crush happens WinDbg starts and you can try to get call stack.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you already know this, but here are some points about minidump debugging:
1. You need to have exactly the same executables and PDB files, as on the client computer where minidump was created, and they should be placed exactly in the same directories. Just rebuilding the same version doesn't help.
2. Debugger must be connected to MS Symbols server.
3. When debugger starts, it prints process loading log in the Output window. Generally, all libraries should be successfully loaded with debug information. Libraries without debug information are loaded as well, but "no debug info" is printed. Learn this log - it can give you some information.

If executable stack contains frames from a library without debug information, it may be not shown. This happens, for example, if your code is running as third-party library callback.

Try to create minidump on your own computer, by adding some code which creates unhandled exception, and debug it immediately. Does this work? Compare loading log in successful and unsuccessful debugging sessions.

Comment: Additional note: how do you create minidump in your code? Compare your code with this sample: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/postmortemdebug_standalone1.aspx

Comment: Actually the host application I'm working with is writing the minidump, so I don't have direct control over this process. Most of the time it works fine, but not it seems when the call stack is wiped.

Answer (score 0):

You may have called null function pointer. Current executing function information is needed to show call stack information. Force set instruction pointer to start of any simple function, then you'll see call stack information again.

```
void SimpleFunc()
{  // <- set next statement here
}
```